# iOS7 Keyboard and Pop-ups flying in bug

Tags: ipad, ios7, keyboard, popup, motion

The keyboard and pop-ups on my iPad app fly-in oddly, however if I 'reduce motion' in the accessibility settings it stops. I've recorded the issue here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gWrQiDySZw

You're help would be invaluable as it's currently driving me insane!!

Thank you!